# Нечто наподобие своего будильника на Android

Tags: android, мобильные-приложения

Хотел узнать как можно выполнять некоторые задачи при закрытом приложении ?

По сути есть необходимость сделать что то типа будильника. Пользователь указывает кол-во часов и минут, и по истечении этого времени (даже если он полностью закрыл приложение), ему кидается уведомление (Notification).

Вопрос в том, как можно выполнять определенные задачи, даже если человек выключил приложение ?

Просто даже не знаю в какую сторону копать :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Копать в сторону [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Примеры использования [тут](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager).